# sqlite CREATE INDEX exec returning an error

Tags: c++, sqlite

I have an existing sqlite database. I am attempting to improve the query performance by using an index. Also I am using a C++ wrapper to sqlite. The return value is SQLITE_ERROR from the sqlite3_exec call below.

wrapper code is as follows to perform exec:

```
Int CppSQLite3DB::execDML(const char* szSQL)
{
checkDB();

char* szError=0;

int nRet = sqlite3_exec(mpDB, szSQL, 0, 0, &szError);

if (nRet == SQLITE_OK)
{
    return sqlite3_changes(mpDB);
}
else
{
    throw CppSQLite3Exception(nRet, szError);
}
}
```

my code to create the index is:

```
sprintf_s( statement, sizeof(statement), "CREATE INDEX modeidx ON Models (manufID)");  
flDB->execDML(statement);
```

The database is open and valid. This section of code is performed following a previous section that reads out of another table in this database. Prior to adding this statement all the code works as expected.

I believe my syntax is correct for creating an index, I do not understand why I am receiving an error.

Comment: What is the type of the `statement` variable? Actually there is no reason to use an intermediate buffer for the SQL statement.

Comment: You could check your statement by entering the sql directly using e.g. the [sqlite firefox addon](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite-manager/). Just to make sure your statement ist correct.

Comment: Print out, or inspect in a debugger, the contents of *szError.  This will give an indication of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. True, statement is not needed. It is a char array. I have checked the sqlite syntax using an external program and it is accepted. szError is just the string that says SQLITE_ERROR.

Comment: Is the database file writeprotected or opened as read-only?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure an index with that name doesn't already exist.  Try: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS modeidx ON Models (manufID)

... and see if you still get an error.